# Retornar un Json por cada iteración de un bucle mvc

Tags: ajax, json, mvc, controller

Hola amigos quiero saber cómo puedo devolver un json desde un bucle forach.?

Estoy enviando un correo electrónico con un bucle y quiero devolver un json con el correo electrónico enviado por cada.

Quiero enviar a la respuesta de front-end.
Para que el cliente vea los correos electrónicos que se envían en tiempo real.

He tratado de esta manera

```
return Json(new {
    emailCount = contadorClientes,
    email = cliente.Email,
    nombreCliente = cliente.Nombre
});
```

Pero esto sale del método. Alguna idea?

Codigo

```
public IActionResult EnviarCorreo(int boletinId)
        {
            int contadorClientes = 0;
            try
            {
                //Con el id del boletin obtengo su informacion.
                var boletin = _boletinService.GetBoletinById(boletinId);

                //Con los rubros asociados al boletin obtengo los clientes
                foreach (var rubro in boletin.SelectedValuesRubros) //para cada rubro
                {
                    var clientes = _clienteService.GetClientesByRubro(rubro); //busco los clientes.
                    if (clientes != null)
                    {
                        //Para cada cliente envio correo.
                        foreach (var cliente in clientes)
                        {
                            //Si es desde generacion de boletin desde la licitacion,
                            //el mensaje debe contener el nombre y la actividad comercial del cliente

                            if (boletin.Mensaje.Contains("{NombreCliente}"))
                            {
                                boletin.Mensaje = boletin.Mensaje.Replace("{NombreCliente}", cliente.Nombre);
                            }

                            //por cada cliente tomo su nombre y correo
                            _emailService.SendEmailAsync(cliente.Email,
                                cliente.Nombre, boletin.Asunto, boletin.Mensaje, boletinId, cliente.ClienteId);
                            contadorClientes++;

                            if (boletin.Mensaje.Contains(cliente.Nombre))
                            {
                                boletin.Mensaje = boletin.Mensaje.Replace(cliente.Nombre, "{NombreCliente}");
                            }

                            return Json(new
                            {
                                emailCount = contadorClientes,
                                email = cliente.Email,
                                nombreCliente = cliente.Nombre
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Tal vez mensaje que diga que para este rubro no hay clientes... O no hacer nada
                    }
                }

                _boletinService.ActualizarEstado(boletinId, eEstadosBoletines.Enviado, DateTime.Now);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new
                {
                    EmailExMessage = ex.Message,
                });

                throw ex;
            }
```

Comment: Hola Hector, bienvenido. Puedes cambiar la foto por el texto del codigo ? Muchas gracias, un saludo

Comment: ¿? Dentro del foreach metes todos los valores de email en una estructura (un array, un String con los valores concatenados) y devuelves esa estructura. ¿Es eso lo que quieres?

Comment: No entendi muy bien. lo que quiero es ir retornando en cada vuelta

Comment: l bucle lo tendrias que hacer en javascript y hacer llamadas asincronas a los action del controller

Comment: ok gracias hermano